# Update/Renew a PAT on a on-prem Azure DevOps intallation

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-devops-rest-api

How do I automatically renew PAT for Azure DevOps on-prem installation?
I see a similar post but there was no solution.
[Generate a PAT for an on-prem DevOps installation using API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74256602/generate-a-pat-for-an-on-prem-devops-installation-using-api).
All the articles and examples I'm seeing are related to Azure DevOps Services(cloud offering)

Comment: What version of Azure DevOps Server are you running?

Comment: @tj-cappelletti Version Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.1